# Replacement for "in order to"

Tags: sentence-construction

Could you please suggest some words  to replace "in order to"?

I am writing a technical paper.

> The fifteen cells have been used in the tip clearance zone **in order to**
>   properly predict interaction between leakage flow and suction surface of turbine blade.

Comment: Can one replace it with _what?_ Please use the [edit] link to add more details to your question. If you don't, it may unfortunately be closed.

Comment: Ok, What should i explain? You say me until i explain more about that. My English language is not good.

Comment: The level of English quoted seems to be quite good. What problems do you have with the phrase *in order to*? It is commonly used in formal English (and technical papers).

Comment: if your English language is not good, why are you attempting to write a technical paper in English? You tell us that you want to replace the expression _in order to,_ but you don't say what  you want to replace it _with!_ There are dozens of ways to rephrase those sentences. You're asking us to proofread.

Comment: Well, I have two reasons:
1. I want to learn more about English language.
2. First, I write all of the paper and then give to a English language expert for editing that. it is better for me and the expert. 
Ok?

Comment: I can't think of any better words to use in this context.

Answer (score 4):

You have three choices here:

- The fifteen cells have been used in the tip clearance zone **in order to** properly predict interaction between leakage flow and suction surface of turbine blade.
- The fifteen cells have been used in the tip clearance zone **to** properly predict interaction between leakage flow and suction surface of turbine blade.
- The fifteen cells have been used in the tip clearance zone **so as to** properly predict interaction between leakage flow and suction surface of turbine blade.

Yet, as you have mentioned that you are writing a technical paper I recommend you use **"in order to"** so as to imply a degree of formality.

More information can be read here http://www.englishgrammar.org/order/

Comment: OK, but i am using "in order to" in my paper very much. so I have to use other words. no?

Comment: It's a formal paper right? You can  interchangeably use 'to' and 'in order to' (preferred) and in some cases, depending on the verb, you can say 'so as to' or a less formal 'so to'.

Comment: Yes. formal paper

Answer (score 1):

The sentence that you gave is perfectly good English (in the area that you are asking about) - but in one other place there's a problem:

> The fifteen cells have been used in the tip clearance zone in order to properly predict interaction between leakage flow and suction surface of ***the*** turbine blade.

And maybe "of" is not strictly correct. If you are talking about the *surface* of the blade, it probably should be:

> The fifteen cells have been used in the tip clearance zone in order to properly predict interaction between leakage flow and suction surface ***at*** the turbine blade.

If for some reason you want to replace "in order to", you can use the following:

> The fifteen cells have been used in the tip clearance zone ***to*** properly predict ***the*** interaction between leakage flow and suction surface of the turbine blade.

The difference is *very* subtle. It's one of emphasis: "in order to" *emphasises* the purpose of the fifteen cells, while the above is just a statement of why you did what you did.

Comment: I think that the OP just wanted some help in defeating an automated plagiarism checker.

Comment: @Mick Naïf that I am, this never occurred to me, but the truth of your statement is obvious.

Comment: Yes. You are right, Mick

Comment: @P.E.Dant I often wonder how much of the help we give here is for that very purpose.

Comment: @user19061 Your level of English is better, I think, than you pretend.

Comment: @user19061 Do you know what "plagiarism" is?

Comment: Yes...But i don't this work. Some sentences are constant in all of researches and papers. but i attempt to change them with my method. Other sentences(approximately 90 % of whole paper) is for myself not others.

Comment: I just give some ideas from papers by studying them .. it in not plagiarism.

Comment: @user19061: It would be plagiarism if you changed the wording, but didn't cite the source. If you change the wording *and* give an in-line citation/footnote citation showing where you got the idea from, it's OK.